# I have a group of bootstrap-multiselects. How can I keep their 'Select All' option from clashing

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a group of bootstrap-multiselects:

```
<div id="filter-div" class="text-center">
    <select id="set" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple"></select>
    <select id="subject" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple"></select>
    <select id="demographic" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple"></select>
    <select id="grade" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple"></select>
</div>
```

and then, I enable them:

```
    $('#filter-div select').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            selectAllValue: 'select-all-value'
    })
```

Then the problem comes: if I click 'Select All' on one of them, the 'Select All' checkboxes on the other multiselects also get checked (not all the options, just the select all one).

Seems I have to assign separate 'select-all-value' to each one of them. Is there an easy way? whether on the bootstrap-multiselect side or jQuery side.

Comment: I fill in the <option> elements programmatically, so they are not shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you click "Select All", the plugin is toggling all inputs with that `selectAllValue` instead of only inputs within that select. Unless they change their code there is nothing you can do except work around it.

Possible workaround it to just add a unique number to each `selectAllValue`.

```
$('#filter-div select').each(function(index, value) {
    $(this).multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        selectAllValue: 'select-all-value-' + index
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k83b9uun/1/)

Comment: That is what I was after. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug that has already been corrected, but it's pull request correction on GitHub wasn't merged to master yet.
The solution alter just two lines of code in the js file:
https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/pull/753/files